# Screen layout broken in firefox ESR on on Centos 6. Would presumably also affect RHEL 6

Tags: bug, status-declined, profile-page, design

I've asked another [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143184/should-stack-exchange-support-esr-releases-of-firefox) about whether ESR versions of firefox merit support effort from the SE development team.

**The issue**

The user page screen layout is broken on Firefox (10.0.4 ESR) on CentOS 6.0.  This is the version maintained by the CentOS distributors, which is presumably the same as the version maintained by Redhat.  I have no idea whether this issue would affect a significant number of SE users.

Similar layout issues occur on Serverfault and Superuser, but not on DBA.SE or any of a sample of non-trio sites I checked (programmers.se, graphic design, english language and usage etc.

For what it's worth, the machine has a Quadro card with the NVidia drivers as opposed to the open-source nv ones.  Otherwise the build is fairly vanilla with no custom kernel.  The output from about:plugins is listed below:

**Example screen shot:**

[image: Screenshot on CentOS 6]

**about:plugins**

```
Find more information about browser plugins at mozilla.org.
Find updates for installed plugins at mozilla.com/plugincheck.
Help for installing plugins is available from plugindoc.mozdev.org.
Shockwave Flash

    File: nswrapper_64_64.libflashplayer.so
    Version: 
    Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

MIME Type   Description     Suffixes
application/x-shockwave-flash   Shockwave Flash     swf
application/futuresplash    FutureSplash Player     spl
QuickTime Plug-in 7.2.0

    File: libtotem-narrowspace-plugin.so
    Version: 
    The Totem 2.28.6 plugin handles video and audio streams.

MIME Type   Description     Suffixes
video/quicktime     QuickTime video     mov
video/mp4   MPEG-4 video    mp4
image/x-macpaint    MacPaint Bitmap image   pntg
image/x-quicktime   Macintosh Quickdraw/PICT drawing    pict, pict1, pict2
video/x-m4v     MPEG-4 video    m4v
VLC Multimedia Plugin (compatible Totem 2.28.6)

    File: libtotem-cone-plugin.so
    Version: 
    The Totem 2.28.6 plugin handles video and audio streams.

MIME Type   Description     Suffixes
application/x-vlc-plugin    VLC Multimedia Plugin   
application/vlc     VLC Multimedia Plugin   
video/x-google-vlc-plugin   VLC Multimedia Plugin   
application/x-ogg   Ogg multimedia file     ogg
application/ogg     Ogg multimedia file     ogg
audio/ogg   Ogg Audio   oga
audio/x-ogg     Ogg Audio   ogg
video/ogg   Ogg Video   ogv
video/x-ogg     Ogg Video   ogg
application/annodex     Annodex exchange format     anx
audio/annodex   Annodex Audio   axa
video/annodex   Annodex Video   axv
video/mpeg  MPEG video  mpg, mpeg, mpe
audio/wav   WAV audio   wav
audio/x-wav     WAV audio   wav
audio/mpeg  MP3 audio   mp3
application/x-nsv-vp3-mp3   NullSoft video  nsv
video/flv   Flash video     flv
application/x-totem-plugin  Totem Multimedia plugin     
audio/midi  MIDI audio  mid, midi
Windows Media Player Plug-in 10 (compatible; Totem)

    File: libtotem-gmp-plugin.so
    Version: 
    The Totem 2.28.6 plugin handles video and audio streams.

MIME Type   Description     Suffixes
application/x-mplayer2  AVI video   avi, wma, wmv
video/x-ms-asf-plugin   ASF video   asf, wmv
video/x-msvideo     AVI video   asf, wmv
video/x-ms-asf  ASF video   asf
video/x-ms-wmv  Windows Media video     wmv
video/x-wmv     Windows Media video     wmv
video/x-ms-wvx  Windows Media video     wmv
video/x-ms-wm   Windows Media video     wmv
video/x-ms-wmp  Windows Media video     wmv
application/x-ms-wms    Windows Media video     wms
application/x-ms-wmp    Windows Media video     wmp
application/asx     Microsoft ASX playlist  asx
audio/x-ms-wma  Windows Media audio     wma
DivX® Web Player

    File: libtotem-mully-plugin.so
    Version: 
    DivX Web Player version 1.4.0.233

MIME Type   Description     Suffixes
video/divx  AVI video   divx
NPAPI Plugins Wrapper 1.3.0

    File: npwrapper.so
    Version: 
    nspluginwrapper is a cross-platform NPAPI plugin viewer, in particular for linux/i386 plugins.
    This beta software is available under the terms of the GNU General Public License.

MIME Type   Description     Suffixes
unknown/mime-type   Do not open     none
iTunes Application Detector

    File: librhythmbox-itms-detection-plugin.so
    Version: 
    This plug-in detects the presence of iTunes when opening iTunes Store URLs in a web page with Firefox.

MIME Type   Description     Suffixes
application/itunes-plugin
```

Comment: Only firefox 13 and 14 are [explicitly supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: @Rory - indeed, the issue will be easy enough to work around by installing a newer version of the browser.  I thought it might be of interest as this is the current vendor supported version on RHEL, at least until RHEL 7 comes out.  This sort of puts it in the same boat as IE 7, although I imagine the user base will be somewhat smaller.  As I do contract work I'm often stuck with the client's build and occasionally with 'no install' policies, so I have had to deal with not having the option of upgrading my browser on more than one occasion.

Comment: Yep, this is Firefox ESR, with a longer support lifecycle for enterprises.

Comment: I guess the question boils down to: "Should SE explicitly support ESR versions of firefox?"

Answer (score -1):

As [Rory notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143174/screen-layout-broken-in-firefox-esr-on-on-centos-6-would-presumably-also-affect#comment406619_143174):

> Only firefox 13 and 14 are [explicitly supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)