# Why does "lang-bash" not highlight a list of commands and their output but adding the [bash] tag to a question does?

Tags: support, tags, syntax-highlighting

Why does `<!-- language-all: lang-bash -->` not highlight a list of commands and their output (like it used to) but adding the [bash] tag (instead) to a question does?

Example question: [FQDN selection in "pg_hba.conf" does not work : DETAIL: Client IP address resolved forward lookup does not match](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/314198)

Here's a screenshot of what I see with `<!-- language-all: lang-bash -->`:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of what I see without `<!-- language-all: lang-bash -->` but with the [bash] tag added to the tags under my question:

[image]

Comment: Works for me here on MSE. On what site do you experience that problem and do you have a link to an example post?

Comment: @rene https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/314198

Comment: Still works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVcpH.png here and I see the same markup on dba.se

Comment: @RobertLongson I've just `<!-- language-all: lang-bash -->` to the top of my post but it still does not work.

Comment: It also works for me, but is subtle against the background color of DBA.SE. Could you provide more details, such as browser used/screenshot?

Comment: @ErikA I use Firefox 91.11esr. but I don't have access to https://i.stack.imgur.com from the office, do you know of another platform I can use to share a screenshot ?

Comment: Hmm... Firefox ESR support is [an item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143184/369403). There are many sites that allow you to publicly share files (Dropbox/OneDrive/Google Drive/etc.) but I do not know of a good one for pictures that doesn't require an account.

Comment: @ErikA, OP: You can use [ImgBB](https://imgbb.com/upload) to upload your pictures and share a link to them. You don't need an account but you can create one if you'd like to save your uploaded pictures. Here's an example: https://ibb.co/Xsrkb4j

Comment: You can include the links to your screenshots in your question and we'll help you edit them into inline images.

Comment: @ErikA [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/ZfJRdZp)

Comment: That has syntax highlighting, notice the green quoted star and slightly grey comment

Comment: @ErikA Yes, but the highlighting is really different if I use the `bash` tag : [screenshot with bash tag instead](https://ibb.co/64GfvT5)

Comment: It is using default/guessed highlighting when you apply the bash tag, because the bash tag does not have a language set for it. In this case, your code is getting highlighted as SQL when you use the tag instead.

Comment: @animuson Thank you four answer, you got it right. If I remove the bash and type `<!-- language-all: lang-sql -->` at the top of my post, it does the same highlighting.

Comment: @animuson Moreover, it seems typing `<!-- sql -->` does the same.

Comment: Re *"like it used to"*: What is the timescale? Days? Months? Years? The [new syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) (2020-09-08) was [updated to a new version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378548/syntax-highlighting-changes-in-the-middle-of-a-token-resolved-in-a-later-versio/379238#379238) (11.5.1) on 2022-06-02.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I'm sorry. I don't remember when "it used to".

Answer (score 3):

> It is using default/guessed highlighting when you apply the `bash` tag, because the bash tag does not have a language set for it. In this case, your code is getting highlighted as SQL when you use the tag instead. - @animuson

Just a quick heads up, NEVER use that to highlight syntax; it is long and annoying :P. I recommend:

````
```lang-bash
Code
```
````

So basically right after your triple back apostrophe, you put `lang-[lang]`. Make sure it is one word though. Short abbreviations of the language name are allowed - but do check if it works in the first place as some don't work; it's always better to not use abbreviations, I guess. E.g.

> `lang-py` or `lang-python`

Both of the above provide the same syntax highlighting.

Check more on [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

You can also put a version number after the language name if you want (although the syntax will choose the latest one anyway and I have observed it makes no changes to syntax for some reason).

Comment: I prefer to use `<!-- language-all: lang-bash -->` because if you have 10 code snippets, you will have to type ```
```lang-bash
```
```
 10 times.

Comment: That's true, but the syntax is messed up for lang all @SebMa

Comment: Re *"Short abbreviations of the language name is allowed"*: The supported aliases are documented in *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)* near *"All the language identifiers"*.