# Rendering a question containing MathJax makes for a really jumpy experience

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, mathjax, page-rendering

As you can see in this animation (slowed down to 50% of original speed) rendering this page that has MathJax enabled is a really jumpy experience.

There are a two things that play into this:

1. There is space reserved (Between the title and the body of the question) for a leader ad, which I earlier mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348103/lazy-loading-our-leaderboard-ads/348111#348111). When there is no add to serve the space then collapses.
2. The MathJax in the post goes through 3 different displays:

   - The markdown, with `$` signs around the equation.
   - A rendered state
   - A final rendered state
3. This is the same for MathJax in comments.

### Could we improve on this?

[image]
 <sub>excuse me for the poor quality, I used a free converter</sub>

For completeness: I browse SE using FireFox 68.5.0ESR on macOs Mojave 10.14.6 and can also replicate this behaviour using Chrome on Android (both on the mobile-web as well as on the full site)

Comment: Suggested title: "MathJax makes posts jumpy. Can we calm them down?"

Comment: Browser forks are not supported, ESR isn't an exception. SE supports only the one main release of each browser, it's mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143837/152859) and doubt the policy changed over the years. (Bottom line: don't expect a fix, and use a main browser to get a better experience.)

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance using Chrome on Android replicates this as well, using both the full site as the mobile-web.