# On the unanswered questions tab, when refreshing due to a new question, MathJax on the page does not render

Tags: bug, live-refresh, mathjax

The title says it all. Recently, a problem was fixed where when an answer was edited, clicking on the answer to refresh resulted in MathJax in the answer not rendering. The same issue happens on the unanswered questions tab when clicking to refresh due to a new question, and this was not fixed with the update.

This is in a sense a worse problem since when the page is refreshed through the browser the new questions that had popped up may not appear afterwards.

Comment: This happens to me all the time as well, I'd like to see it fixed.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349490/rendering-a-question-containing-mathjax-makes-for-a-really-jumpy-experience

Comment: I just witnessed it also happens in the review queue.